# Node.js passport authentication existing user message

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, passport.js

I'm using Node.js Express to build my app. I'm using passport as my authentication system.

I'm a Python dev so I'm new to JS. How can I alter my code so if a user exists, it says "User already exists" as a pop up message on the current screen?

Currently it clears the page and just displays "User already exists"

```
passport.use('signup-local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: "email",
    passwordField: "password"
}, function(email, password, next) {
    User.findOne({
        email: email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (user) return next({message: "User already exists"});
        let newUser = new User({
            email: email,
            passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10)
        })
        newUser.save(function(err) {
            next(err, newUser);
        });
    });
}));



app.post('/signup',
    passport.authenticate('signup-local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Comment: You didn't show how your frontend works